# Steps required to port from QNX to open source RTOS

Tags: c++, rtos, qnx

What are the options available as an open source alternatives to QNX neutrino OS ?
Also what are the steps involved in porting code from QNX to other RTOS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The API of QNX Neurino is [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). Therefore, what you are implicitly looking for is an open-source RTOS with POSIX API. This will allow to easily port your existing application code to the new RTOS.

Among such free RTOSs you can find:

- [RTEMS](https://www.rtems.org/)
- [NuttX](http://nuttx.org/), which [appears to be POSIX certified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)
- [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/), which implements a [*subset* of the POSIX API](http://interactive.freertos.org/entries/20367041-POSIX-Wrapper-for-FreeRTOS).

Finally, all RTOSs based on Linux/FreeBSD are POSIX compliant; you therefore may want to have a look at [RTAI](https://www.rtai.org/) or [Xenomai](http://xenomai.org/).